# MySQL Añadir llave foranea a nueva columna

Tags: mysql

Estaba trabajando normalmente con estas lineas para añadir mis llaves foraneas, pero ahora no funciona, me sale error :

> error #1072 - Key column 'categorias' doesn't exist in table

ALTER TABLE subcat ADD COLUMN id_cat INT(11) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE subcat ADD CONSTRAINT id_cat FOREIGN KEY (categorias) REFERENCES id_cat(categorias);

Como lo puedo arreglar?

Mis tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios (
    id_u INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    u_nombres VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    u_apellidos VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    u_numdoc INT(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    u_email VARCHAR(60) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_u)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

/* Tabla tipo de usuario, en la aplicación solo existen dos tipos
cliente o prestador de servicios */
/*DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 't_usuarios';*/
CREATE TABLE t_usuarios (
    id_tipu INT(11) NOT NULL,
    tipu_nombre VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    tipu_desc VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_tipu)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

/*DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'categorias';*/
CREATE TABLE categorias (
    id_cat INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cat_nombre VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    cat_desc VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_cat)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

/*DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'subcat';*/
CREATE TABLE subcat (
    id_subcat INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    subcat_nombre VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    subcat_desc VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_subcat)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

/*DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'servicios';*/
CREATE TABLE servicios (
    id_serv INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_u INT(11) NOT NULL,
    id_tipu INT(11) NOT NULL,
    id_cat INT(11) NOT NULL,
    id_subcat INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_serv),
     FOREIGN KEY(id_u) REFERENCES usuarios(id_u),
     FOREIGN KEY(id_tipu) REFERENCES t_usuarios(id_tipu),
     FOREIGN KEY(id_cat) REFERENCES categorias(id_cat),
     FOREIGN KEY(id_subcat) REFERENCES subcat(id_subcat) 
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Hola. Muestra los `CREATE TABLE` de las tablas que quieres modificar. Parece que la columna `categorias` no existe en la tabla. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que anda mal es la referencia, ya que lo que se está indicando en su consulta es que haga la referencia a la tabla id_cat mediante la columna categorias.

```
REFERENCES id_cat(categorias);
```

Lo cual supongo no es esa la idea y por eso se indica en el mensaje de error que el campo categorias no existe.

La estructura del foreign key es la siguiente

```
CONSTRAINT fk_nombre_de_llave_foranea FOREIGN KEY (columna_o_campo_de_llave) REFERENCES nombre_tabla_referenciada(columna_de_esa_tabla).
```

**En tu caso suponiendo que tienes 2 tablas (subcat y categorias) y que ambas tienen la columna de id_cat por la cual quieres referenciarlas, entonces la corrección a la consulta es:**

```
TABLE subcat ADD CONSTRAINT fk_subcat_categorias FOREIGN KEY (id_cat) REFERENCES categorias(id_cat);
```

Comment: Gracias, a quedado la llave foranea creada.

Answer (score 1):

El problema tiene toda la pinta de estar aquí:

```
REFERENCES id_cat(categorias);
```

Pues se debe poner la tabla y, entre paréntesis, el campo al que vincular tu clave ajena. Así:

```
REFERENCES categorias(id_cat);
```

Si no fuera eso, ejecuta:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE categorias;
```

Y modifica tu pregunta con el resultado que obtengas para que podamos continuar ayudándote.

Comment: al dejarlo como dices:
ALTER TABLE subcat ADD CONSTRAINT id_cat FOREIGN KEY (categorias) REFERENCES categorias(id_cat);
sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje "error code" 1072

Comment: Sin ver las tablas, un error se podía intuir, dos ya... :)